# Azure webjobs deployment and working directory

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-webjobs, kudu

I'm confused about deployment webjobs to azure.

I'm using .net core, so I manaully publish my webjobs in my `deploy.cmd` file, for example like this:

`call :ExecuteCmd dotnet publish "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\My.WebJobs\Mt.WebJobs.csproj" --output "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\App_Data\Jobs\Continuous\MyWebJobs" --configuration Release`

That then deploys the webjob to the `deployment_temp` folder. After that, KuduSync kicks in and syncs to `DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` which is `d:\home\site\wwwroot` I can see in there if I look, that there is a `App_Data\Jobs\Continuous\MyWebJobs` folder, and that ALL my files have been correctly deployed and sync-ed up to that folder.

However, when I run the webjob, it reports it's running from a totally different location (`D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\MyCustomerIO\bp003r3f.h2g`). And when I look in that folder, I see most of my deployed webjob files, but some JSON configuration files that are in `App_Data...` are missing from here.

So - why is my webjob running from here? And why are some of my deployed files missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why is my webjob running from here?

The WebJob is copied to a temporary directory under `%TEMP%\jobs\{job type}\{job name}\{random name}` and will run from there. This option **prevents the original WebJob binaries from being locked** which might cause issues redeploying the WebJob.

The WebJob is run directly from the WebJob binaries directory. We call this option in place. This option can have the locking issue and should only be used when there is no risk of locking the file.

**By default** the first option is used (**in place = false**).You can explicitly configure this setting in your settings.job. e.g.

```
{ "is_in_place": true/false }
```

> And why are some of my deployed files missing?

I tested and reproduced this situation too. But I did not find solution to solve this. I suggest that you could use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBJOBS_ROOT_PATH");` to get the root path 
 direcroty of webjob.

**WEBJOBS_ROOT_PATH** which is location of webjob files, you can specify an absolute path, or otherwise the value will be combined with the default root path:

`D:/home/site/wwwroot/ + WEBJOBS_ROOT_PATH(relative)` to get webjob_name, webjob_run_id and so on.

For more detail, you could read this [article](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#settingsjob-reference).